# Getting RasterSymbolizer from a StyledLayerDescriptor?

Tags: geotools

We are using Geotools for a Java GIS project. I have an org.geotools.styling.StyledLayerDescriptor object created from a XML stream and would like to create an org.geotools.styling.RasterSymbolizer from it.

How do I go about to do this?

The documentation (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/index.html) does not give any examples for raster symbolizers.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found an answer in `geoserver/src/extension/sldService/src/test/java/org/geoserver/sldservice/rest/ClassifierTest.java` amounting to something like this:

```
    static StyledLayerDescriptor getSLD(InputStream in) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        Configuration config = new SLDConfiguration();
        Parser parser = new Parser(config);
        StyledLayerDescriptor sld =
                (StyledLayerDescriptor) parser.parse(in);
        return sld;
    }

    static List<Rule> getRules(StyledLayerDescriptor sld) {
        NamedLayer layer = (NamedLayer) sld.getStyledLayers()[0];
        Style style = layer.getStyles()[0];
        java.util.List<FeatureTypeStyle> featureTypeStyles = style.featureTypeStyles();
        assertEquals(1, featureTypeStyles.size());
        return featureTypeStyles.get(0).rules();
    }

    static RasterSymbolizer getRasterSymbolizer(StyledLayerDescriptor sld) {
        List<Rule> rules = getRules(sld);
        assertEquals(1, rules.size());
        List<Symbolizer> symbolizers = rules.get(0).symbolizers();
        assertEquals(1, symbolizers.size());
        assertThat(symbolizers.get(0), instanceOf(RasterSymbolizer.class));
        return (RasterSymbolizer) symbolizers.get(0);
    }
```